# Dafny: Why I input an array Dafny says it is a sequence

Tags: arrays, sequence, mismatch, dafny

It is really clear that the input is an array, but why when it proceeds flag[1..],it says flag is a sequence?
Here is the link:
http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/fUgu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an array `A` and integers `lo` and `hi`, the expression `A[lo..hi]` returns the sequence (not array) of `hi-lo` elements from `A` starting at index `lo`.  For your program, I would recommend either making all your functions operate on sequences or (probably better for your program) adding `lo` and `hi` parameters to all the functions to delineate the part of the array that you are interested in.

Comment: @Lilac Liu, Hi, I am struggling with seq and array in Dafny too. have you found a way to convert seq to array by any chance?

Comment: method SeqToArray<T>(s: seq<T>) returns (a: array<T>)
      ensures fresh(a) && a[..] == s
    {
      a := new T[|s|](i requires 0 <= i < |s| => s[i]);
    }